# Importing picasso library

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm having problems when I try to rebuild my module. It says:

> Failed to resolve: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2

Here's my code:

```js
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat.

Comment: that's compile time error i guess, check if you have enabled offline work in settings in studio.
file->settings->build->gradle

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart in android studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a section `allprojects` at the end of your main build.gradle that defines the repositories for the modules of your project:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

it will work for sure. Thanks

Comment: Where exactly do I have to put it?

Comment: In your project build.gradle

Comment: check if you have enabled offline work in settings gradle

Comment: @vikaskumar Where do you see that?

Comment: file->settings->build->gradle

Comment: @vikaskumar it's unchecked by default, I tried checking it and rebuild the project again and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding using alternate method if network is working and  not checked offline work.
[image]

[image]

[image]